# How to upload/import a file in the new R shiny version 0.12 using DT package

Tags: r, datatable, upload, shiny

I have just updated shiny to version 0.12 and started to use the DT package (finding it a bit difficult to use but have to do it anyway). Basically I am trying to upload or import a file. This is my server code:

```
 shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

    datasetInput <- reactive({
      infile <- input$FileInput
      if(is.null(infile))
        return(NULL)
      read.table(infile$datapath,header=input$header,sep=input$sep,check.names=F)
    })

    output$table = DT::renderDataTable(datasetInput(), server = TRUE)
    })

    # Also tried the following code but get the same error & warning:
    # output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({
    #    DT::datatable(datasetInput())
    # },server=TRUE)
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
Error in datatable(instance, ...) : 
  'data' must be either a matrix or a data frame
```

and the following warning, despite using `server = TRUE`:

```
Warning in run(timeoutMs) :
  It seems your data is too big for client-side DataTables. You may consider server-side processing: http://rstudio.github.io/DT/server.html
```

I know this is very basic, I couldn't find any example that uses the DT package to import data from a file. More questions will pop up for sure, because I am just starting to move everything from 0.11 to 0.12.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code is fine.  Are you sure you're updated to the absolute latest `shiny` and `DT`? Both of them have been updated pretty heavily the past couple weeks, so make sure you install their GitHub version. I would guess that one of the packages is not up to date.  Note that with the new version you don't need to specify `server = TRUE` as that's the new default.

Here's code that I just used and I was able to read a file and display it. It's a simplification from you code because I didn't want to implement the header and sep inputs.  Next time please include the full source code including the UI to make it easier for us and more reproducible :)

```
runApp(shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    fileInput("FileInput", "Choose file"),
    DT::dataTableOutput("table")
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    datasetInput <- reactive({
      infile <- input$FileInput
      if(is.null(infile))
        return(NULL)
      read.csv(infile$datapath, header = TRUE)
    })

    output$table = DT::renderDataTable(datasetInput())
  }
))
```

Note that I do see the `'data' must be either a matrix or a data frame` message initially but after choosing a file it goes away. This is because the datatable is trying to get initialized with a `NULL` value which apparently throws that error (I would argue it should just not display anything silently rather than have an error, but that's the case). To solve that small issue, just change the `reactive` to a `eventReactive` so that it will only fire once a file has been chosen

```
runApp(shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    fileInput("FileInput", "Choose file"),
    DT::dataTableOutput("table")
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    datasetInput <- eventReactive(input$FileInput, {
      infile <- input$FileInput
      read.csv(infile$datapath, header = TRUE)
    })

    output$table = DT::renderDataTable(datasetInput())
  }
))
```

Comment: I am using `DT_0.0.64` and `shiny_0.12.0`. I'll try to install the GitHub version & see if the errors go away.

Comment: Those are actually very recent versions. To make sure we're doing exactly the same thing, why don't use try running my code (the second version, the one that doesn't have the initial error) on the iris data. Just run `write.csv(iris, "iris.csv")` to write out the iris table to a file and then load that same file with my code.  It should work.

Comment: Actually, I just updated shiny using the GitHub version which is `shiny_0.12.0.9002` and my code worked. Thanks a lot for pointing that out!

Comment: Note that it looks like the NULL issue was **just** fixed an hour ago - https://github.com/rstudio/DT/issues/92 so now you can use the first version of my code without error as well